# On Giuga numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory

I am studying Giuga numbers and I am reading a paragraph that says all Giuga numbers $n$ satisfy the property $\left(\sum_{p|n}1/p\right) - 1/n \in \mathbb{N}$ and beside it says that all known Giuga numbers also satisfy $\sum_{p|n}{1}/{p} - 1/n = 1$. So is it proven or just a conjecture?

Comment: I've fixed your English (and formatting) which has many mistakes (this is not a problem — typically users here do such corrections), I'm not sure why you rolled back.

Comment: I reinstated your corrections, @YCor .

Comment: @YCor sorry I didn't knew what rollback I thought it will apply the change but it didn't happen

Comment: Note that $\sum_{p\mid n}(1/p)>2$ implies $n$ is divisible by at least 30 different primes, so the kind of $n$ you ask about, if it exists, is going to be rather large.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The prime factors of a [Giuga number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuga_number) are all distinct; hence the equality in the OP is equivalent to
$$\sum_{p|n}1/p - \prod_{p|n}1/p =\nu\in \mathbb{N},$$
which was proven by Giuga in his original paper (as stated in [Borwein et al.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2975213?origin=JSTOR-pdf)). The 13 known Giuga numbers all satisfy $\nu=1$, it is unknown whether this is true for all Giuga numbers (see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A007850)).